# .htaccess redirect to subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i having problem with .htacess redirect URL's to sub-folders (sub-directory).
My Folder Structure was like. i had two directories in my root folder web and sales.

**Root**

**Directory 1** - web/4.5 ,
**Directory 2** - sales/2.5

And my main URL site was like **http ://beta.example.com**

when user hits the root URL (**http ://beta.example.com**) it should redirect to sub-folder name **web/4.5** for this i wrote code and it was working.the code was like.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/4.5
RewriteRule (.*) /web/4.5/$1
```

the above code was working but,
when user hits the root URL (**http ://beta.example.com/sales/**) it should redirect to sub-folder **sales/2.5** for this i wrote code and it was not working.the code was like.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sales/(.*) sales/2.5/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/4.5
RewriteRule (.*) /web/4.5/$1
```

it was not working ,it goes to **web/4.5/sales/2.5/** ,actually it goes to **/sales/2.5/**

  -

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sales/2.5
RewriteRule ^sales/(.*) /sales/2.5/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sales/2.5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/4.5
RewriteRule (.*) /web/4.5/$1
```

The  [L]  stops following redirect processes.

Comment: Thanks ,but it was not working it still goes to web/2.5/ , here my problem was when user enter http ://beta.example.com/sales it redirect to sales/2.5/ folder but it goes to web/ folder  and after you suggestion i wrote like                                 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On   
  
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta.lytepole\.com$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/4.0
 RewriteRule (.*) /web/4.0/$1
 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sales/3.6
 RewriteRule ^/sales/(.*) /sales/3.6/$1 [L]
 
</IfModule>

Comment: Sorry, now I modified my answer. I check   ^/sales/2.5  in each  ReriteRule.