# .htaccess reroute to sub-directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, api

I have site I am running on localhost `http://example` and I have directory in the root that contains my api so it's `http://example/api`

In the `api` folder I have my root directory for the api which is `public` directory. so `/api/public/...`.

I want to have a .htaccess that redirects the user to the `public` directory when they hit `http://example/api/{api parameters}`. So I can have a clean url without having to write this `http://example/api/public/{api parameters}`

I tried this but to no avail

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) /api/public/$1 [L]
```

I got the above from a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126244/htaccess-redirect-to-subfolders)  but still could not get it to work.

Comment: Just remove the ``RewriteCond`` line and you should be fine.

Comment: Though the question is what you actually refer to by "api parameters" and how to handle those...

Comment: @arkascha doesn't work.

Comment: And "doesn't work" means _what_ exactly?

Comment: @arkascha sorry, I get Object not Found! Request url not found on this server

Comment: What is the URL you try? And _what_ object is not found? Please provide the answers from what you can see in your http servers error log file.

Comment: @arkascha when I use `http://example/api/public/myparameter` I get the out I want from my endpoint. How can I bypass the public directory for a clean url. That's the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133390/discussion-between-arkascha-and-bos570).

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/public/
```

Quoting a [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704102/how-does-rewritebase-work-in-htaccess), "By having the RewriteBase there, you make the relative path come off the RewriteBase parameter."

With this method I believe you will have to rewrite all paths that don't fall under the base directory. If this is a problem, you could create a rule for each page.

Update: You might be able to write a rule that checked for files at that path before/after it checks for the relative path.